# Unable to Git add

Tags: git

```
root@bbaec70634de:/alx-low_level_programming/0x0D-preprocessor# git add .
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
root@bbaec70634de:/alx-low_level_programming/0x0D-preprocessor#
```

I wanted to git add . my work on my Webterm to my GitHub but kept getting that error

Comment: _"not a git repository"_ seems reasonably straight forward error message. What makes you think you _are_ operating in a Git repository folder?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your git repo first. Try `git init` or clone an existing repo in your git server.